# Convert Multiple Audio Tracks of Multiple Files FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sh

I'm using a script to convert all video files in a folder. These files have multiple audio tracks and I want the converted files to have each audio track as well. I've tried both `-c copy` and `-c:a mp3` and neither worked for me. Any ideas how I can modify this to copy all audio tracks?

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:a mp3 -vcodec libx264 -crf 18 -r 60 "${i%.mkv}.mp4"; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting `-c:a copy`. In your example you're attempting to  set the audio codec to `mp3`, which is actually just the container. Hope that helps!

---

I should amend this... My first thought will simply copy the single, highest-quality audio stream from the input file. To copy all streams we'll want to use the `map` option[1](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map#Example4). Your example, copying all audio streams could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in *.mkv; do
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -r 60 "${i%.mkv}.mp4"; 
done
```